# *** Error in `': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000667890 ***

Tags: c++

This was a function that i made, it calculated Fibonacci Numbers, but when I run it i get the following error

> Error in `': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000667890

```
int fib(int n) {
int fibn=0;
std::vector<int> x{0,1};
for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
{
    x[i]=x[i-2]+x[i-1]; 
}
fibn=x[n];
return fibn;
}
```

Comment: your vector is of size 2 and you index at [2] (i.e. size 3) and more, this is invalid code. you probably meant to push_back(...) the new values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<int> x{0,1};
> ```

You have a vector with two elements. Valid indices are 0 and 1.

> ```
> for(int i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
> {
>     x[i]=x[i-2]+x[i-1]; 
> }
> ```

After the first iteration, you access `x[2]` and beyond which is outside the bounds of the vector. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

You don't need to store the series in a vector since you're only returning the last value. You only need to store the last two values.

Answer (score 3):

Your vector `x` only has 2 elements, but your loop starts by setting `i` to `2` and then does `x[i]` (aka `x[2]`) on the first iteration, which is out of bounds since only the indices `0` and `1` are valid.
Remember that array indices start at `0` in C++.

Accessing out of bounds is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and as a result your entire program is invalid and the compiler is not required to generate anything sensible, nor is it obliged to tell you about your error.